# Monorepo with `rootDirs` produces unwanted sudirectories such as `src` in `outDir`

Tags: typescript, dependencies, tsconfig, monorepo

I am planning a monorepo typescript project like below:

```
/ (root)
+--backend/
|  +-src/
|  \-tsconfig.json
+--shared/
|  \-src/
\--frontend/
   \-src/
```

`tsconfig.json` is defined like below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "shared": [
        "../../shared/src"
      ]
    },
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src",
      "../shared/src"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

When I execute `tsc` under `backend` it gives me like below:

```
/ (root)
+-backend/
  +-dist/
  | +-backend/
  | | +-src/
  | \-shared/
  |   \-src/
  +-src/
  \-tsconfig.json
```

In the above, `dist` contains `backend` and `shared` BUT each of them contains `src` under it. I wanted `backend` and `shared` under `dist` contain compiled JS files without `src`:

```
/ (root)
+-backend/
  +-dist/
  | +-backend/
  | \-shared/
  +-src/
  \-tsconfig.json
```

Is it possible ? And how can I make it ?

Answer (score 20):

#### diagnosis

- Typescript relies on `rootDir` (not `rootDirs`) to decide the directory structure of the output (see [this comment from Typescript's bossman](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9858#issuecomment-370537216)).
- When you set multiple `rootDirs`, `tsc` will find the parent directory that is common to all of them and treat *that* as the `rootDir`. *This is why you're getting the `outDir` structure that you're getting.*

#### prescription: *Structure your monorepo as separate Typescript sub-projects*

A *Typescript project* is defined by a **tsconfig** file, is self-contained, and is *effectively* bounded by its `rootDir`. This is a very good thing, as it lines up with **principles of encapsulation**.

You can have multiple projects (e.g. a main and a set of libs) each in their own directory with their own  tsconfig, with their own `rootDir`.  **Dependencies between them are managed** in the tsconfig files using Typescript [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

> It's unfortunate that the Typescript folks chose the term "projects", as intuitively it refers to the whole shebang, but "modules" and "packages" was already taken. But if you think of them as *subprojects* and it will make a lot more sense.

But I recommend you structure your repo like so:

```
.
├── dist
└── src
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── shared
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    ├── backend
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    └── frontend
        ├── index.ts
        └── tsconfig.json
```

So that when you compile your code you get:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── shared
│   ├── backend
│   └── frontend
└── src
```

**Example tsconfigs**

- **`src/tsconfig.json`**

  Even if you have no code at the root, this tsconfig can be where
  all the common settings go (the others will inherit from it), and
  it will enable a simple `tsc --build src` to build the whole
  project (and with `--force` to build it from scratch).

  ```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "../dist/",
      },
      "files": [],
      "references": [
        { "path": "./shared" },
        { "path": "./backend" },
        { "path": "./frontend" }
      ]
    }
  ```

  - **`src/shared/tsconfig.json`**

    *shared* won't import any of the other projects as it has no references. All it imports are limited to within its directory and
    dependencies listed in `package.json`. You could even restrict the
    the latter, I believe, by giving it its own `package.json`.

    ```
      {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "rootDir": ".",
          "outDir": "../../dist/shared",
          "composite": true
        }
      }
    ```
  - **`src/backend/tsconfig.json`**

    *backend* can import *shared* because of the declared reference.

    ```
      {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "rootDir": ".",
          "outDir": "../../dist/backend",
          "composite": true
        },
        "references": [
          { "path": "../shared" }
        ]
      }
    ```
  - **`src/frontend/tsconfig.json`**

    *frontend* can import *shared* AND *backend* because of the declared references.

    ```
      {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "rootDir": ".",
          "outDir": "../../dist/frontend",
          "composite": true
        },
        "references": [
          { "path": "../shared" },
          { "path": "../backend" }
        ]
      }
    ```

**Example build commands**

`tsc --build src` will build the entire src tree

`tsc --build src/backend` will build the the backend AND shared (if there have been changes since the last build.

Comment: Just wanted to shout out this excellent answer, it's the only one that did the trick for me after a day of spelunking different reference project structures out there in blog posts.

Comment: example code https://github.com/ozknemoy/node-ts-nodemon-starter/tree/ts-starter-app_3-tsconfigs

Comment: My VS Code resolves the module's code when you type it by hand, but it won't autoimport for some reason.