# how to use multiple tsconfig files (with conflicting compiler options)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, web-worker, tsconfig

My codebase contains two typescript projects:

- for a react web app
- for web workers

The web worker codebase is part of my `public/` folder. Which means that there are two typescript projects in the same workspace. How can I make this work with vs-code ?

So far my question is basically a duplicate of: [How to use multiple tsconfig files in vs-code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579969/how-to-use-multiple-tsconfig-files-in-vs-code)

The accepted answer explains how to set up a basic configuration and then extend it:

```
//tsconfig.worker.json:

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "src/app"
  ]
}
```

But this doesn't work in my case. For the `worker.ts` I need a different `lib` configuration than for the react app.
It is possible to override that configuration in my `tsconfig.worker.json` and to compile with the new settings. But for autocompletion and error highlighting, vs-code only uses the `tsconfig.json`, which is not compatible with the webworker source code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

give each project its own `tsconfig.json` in the same directory as the project, like so:

```
└── src
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── shared
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    ├── backend
    │   ├── index.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    └── frontend
        ├── index.ts
        └── tsconfig.json
```

Put all the common settings in the root `tsconfig.json`, and the project specific ones in the its own `tsconfig.json`. DO NOT name them anything other than `tsconfig.json`.

Make sure each dependent config extends the root config and has the correct path to it, e.g.:

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The `rootDir` setting for each subprojects will by default be `./`, which means they will be nicely self-contained / encapsulated. But if the root config changed that value, you will probably have to override it in each `tsconfig.json`.

You can enable and manage dependencies between subprojects using *Project References*, [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61513685/8910547).