# Disable Typescript's noImplicitAny only for .js files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to keep `noImplicitAny` for `.ts`/`.tsx` files, but disable it for `.js` files. I don't want to disable the `checkJs` option because I still want it to check `.js` files.

Is this possible?

Here's my base `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": [
    "."
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./build"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If your .js and .ts files are in a different places, then you could make use of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611311/how-to-use-multiple-tsconfig-files-with-conflicting-compiler-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not something you can achieve like that.
One way you could achieve that would be to have two `tsconfig` file.

So basically, the main `tsconfig.json` would do everything except `checkJs` and the second one (let's call it `tsconfig.typeCheckJs.json`) would add the `checkJs`, `notImplicitAny` and `noEmit`.

For example

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": [
    "."
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./build"
  ]
}
```

and another one

```
// tsconfig.typeCheckJs.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "types": ["node"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "composite": true
  },
  "include": [
    "."
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./build"
  ]
}
```

then, you need to update your scripts to something like this:

```
// package.json
scripts: {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc --project tsconfig.typeCheckJs.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc"
}
```

Hope that it is clear, otherwise do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I think your config is wrong, but disabling checkJs and checking JS using a separate config worked! Need to wait a few hours to award bounty

Comment: ahah oups sorry, I used `*` in the include instead of `.` but I think you've got the idea :)

Comment: Nevermind, I thought `checkJs` was enabled by default, so `checkJs: false` was needed. Since it's disabled by default, it's not needed. But yeah I got the idea, thanks

Comment: My pleasure, no worries, I will wait for the bounty :)